# How to handle two intents in an utterance from LUIS?

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

An example would be:

```
"I would like to do Task 1 then I would like to do Task 2".
```

Here task 1 and 2 represents intents

I want to handle these kinds of complex utterances in the C# code, and post the result using `context.PostAsync()` seperately each time.

Output:

```
Result of task 1

Result of task 2
```

There is a method called `DispatchToLuisHandler()` in Bot Builder 3.8 and above, will it help, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, it is not possible to handle two intents using a single utterance in LUIS. If you really want to do it you should consider preprocessing the user input before sending it to LUIS. But that would make the bot too complex.